# Mongo atomicity between an insert and an update on same collection

Tags: mongodb, transactions

I know there is no straight forward approach for this, but just i want to know what is the better possible way to achieve this. 
I am doing an insert into a Collection and then updating some other record(at most one field) now i want to do these two operations atomically so whats the better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known as 'multi-doc' or 'two-phase' commit;

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/